# database size limitations

Tags: sql-server

I am accidental DBA. One of my clients has been trying to upload a data file and he's been encountering  error message about database size limitation. He hasn't sent us the exact error information but has asked if the database is set to autosize. I have heard tables being set to auto resize, database autoshrink feature..but what exactly is database autosize? I checked the database properties and the data file is set an initial size and autogrowth is enabled and is set to unrestricted growth and the transaction log has a restricted growth feature enabled.
Could you help me here?

Comment: Wait for the exact error. It may actually have nothing to do with the database.

Comment: You should ask the client about the SQL server version - express, standard, etc. Based on your dilemma, I guess the are running EXPRESS edition. Autogrowth has nothing to do - it just means that when the database is full, it will grow by the amount specified in the auto growth setting.

Comment: `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS ProductVersion, SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel') AS ProductLevel, SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') AS Edition;` Execute that query and report back

Comment: It is sql server enterprise version, a cluster that hosts several databases. The client said he is trying to import a data file not upload and he gets an error message about database size limitation . I am still waiting on the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

Database size is limited in the express edition only. In other editions the size is limited only to your storage subsystem restrictions. If it is not express edition, ask your client if it is the full transaction log file issue which he is interpreting as a database size limitation. In that case you either need to back up the log files or increase log file size or truncate the log file with dbcc, depending on your database environment, storage subsystem and recovery model.